# Laravel pagination problem when deleting item

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I'm getting an empty page after deleting products from second page in pagination, I have two pages in pagination the first page with 4 products and the second page with 1 product so if I delete the product from the second page it shows empty page which means I have no products instead of displaying the first page with 4 products. How do I fix this?

Controller

```
 $products = product::where('admin', $userId)->paginate(4);
```

Blade template

```
 <div class="pagination">
     {{ $products->render() }}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller:

```php
$products = Product::where('admin', $userId)->paginate(4);

if (request()->get('page') > 1 && $products->isEmpty()) {
    return redirect()->route('your_route_name');
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says `127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.` @Welder

Comment: Run dd($products->total(), $products->count()) and tell me the result

Comment: Try removing the page (?page=2) argument from the query string, refresh and click on a page link once again. On another matter, are you requesting the controller via ajax?

Comment: I'm not requesting controller via ajax, If I remove `?page=2` and refresh it redirects to the first page @Welder

Comment: Isn't that what you want? If the page=2 is empty, you go back to the page that showed results